# Using VBA how do I call up the Adobe Create PDF function

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, acrobat

```
  Sheets("Key Indicators").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF,
 Filename:=ArchivePath, Quality:=xlQualityStandard,
 IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
         :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Currently this is what I have.

I understand how to ExportAsFixedFormat PDF but what I need to know how to do is to access the Create PDF function under Acrobat (As show in the picture below) using VBA. If I do ExportAsFixedFormat the links get flattened. Acrobat "Create PDF" would allow me to convert an Excel to PDF with hyperlinks included.

[image: AdobePDFMakerForOffice]

How would I do that?

I am using Excel 2016 and Adobe Pro DC

[image]
These are my adobe references

Comment: Does the Acrobat add-in provide an API? an object model? *anything* that's programmatically accessible from VBA? If not, you might have to resort to *SendKeys*, which is a horrible, horrible way of doing things. What's wrong with saving as PDF? What does the Adobe add-in do that Excel doesn't already?

Comment: If I save as PDF normally it will flatten all of the links in the document.

Comment: [This](http://superuser.com/a/921280/165271) might help

Comment: Related to @Mat'sMug comment, have you tried to add the reference for Adobe Acrobat and see the available commands there? (References->Adobe Acrobat)

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: In Excel VBA Editor, go to Tools->References-> Look for something that resembles acrobat. See attached images for reference
Image1: http://s20.postimg.org/3qxr9vqpp/Capture.png   Image2: http://s20.postimg.org/iuoirq2gt/Capture.png

Comment: It is true that the builtIn PDF Publishing only retains Web URLs, Hyperlinks that goes to another Range in the workbook are removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acrobat Reference should work 
[Here is the guide from Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/iac_developer_guide.pdf)
Once added, you may use the following code
Tip: It may lead you to correct coding -I'm not quite sure since I coded it "blindly" because I don't have Acrobat in my PC-. Debug step by step to see what's doing.

```
Sub ExportWithAcrobat()
Dim AcroApp As Acrobat.CAcroApp 'I'm not quite sure it's needed since we are creating the doc directly
Dim AcrobatDoc As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc
Dim numPages As Long
Dim WorkSheetToPDF As Worksheet
Const SaveFilePath = "C:\temp\MergedFile.pdf"
    Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App") 'I'm not quite sure it's needed since we are creating the doc directly
    Set AcrobatDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
    'it's going to be 0 at first since we just created
    numPages = AcrobatDoc.GetNumPages
    For Each WorkSheetToPDF In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If AcrobatDoc.InsertPages(numPages - 1, WorkSheetToPDF, 0, AcrobatDoc.GetNumPages(), True) = False Then 'you should be available to work with the code to see how to insert the sheets that you want in the created object ' 1. If Part1Document.InsertPages(numPages - 1, "ExcelSheet?", 0, AcrobatDoc.GetNumPages(), True) = False
    MsgBox "Cannot insert pages" & numPages
    Else ' 1. If Part1Document.InsertPages(numPages - 1, "ExcelSheet?", 0, AcrobatDoc.GetNumPages(), True) = False
    numPages = numPages + 1
    End If ' 1. If Part1Document.InsertPages(numPages - 1, "ExcelSheet?", 0, AcrobatDoc.GetNumPages(), True) = False
    Next WorkSheetToPDF
    If AcrobatDoc.Save(PDSaveFull, SaveFilePath) = False Then ' 2. If Part1Document.Save(PDSaveFull, "C:\temp\MergedFile.pdf") = False
    MsgBox "Cannot save the modified document"
    End If ' 2. If Part1Document.Save(PDSaveFull, "C:\temp\MergedFile.pdf") = False
End Sub
```

Following pages may provide better assistance: [Link1](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/853854), [Link2](http://www.khk.net/wordpress/2009/03/04/adobe-acrobat-and-vba-an-introduction/)

Comment: Refer to the documentation and try to "play" combining them with the codes provided at the bottom, can't code further since I don't have Acrobat.

Answer (score 3):

```
Sub PDF()
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\PCNAME\Documents\Book1.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
    True
End Sub
```

Please try the above codes

Comment: The problem is that without calling up Adobe, the hyperlinks do not transfer to PDF

Answer (score 1):

```
With ActiveSheet
    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="N:\JKDJKDJ", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True,  
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
End With
```

Comment: worth noting my links don't get flattened when using this approach

Answer (score 1):

You can publish any Excel Range as a PDF using ExportAsFixedFormat.  There is no need to set a refernce to Acrobat.

```
' Usage:
' PublishRangePDF(Thisworkbook, fileName) : Will Publish the entire Workbook
' PublishRangePDF(AvtiveSheet, fileName) : Will Publish all selected worksheets
' PublishRangePDF(Range("A1:H100"), fileName) : Will Publish Range("A1:H100")


Sub PublishRangePDF(RangeObject As Object, fileName As String, Optional OpenAfterPublish As Boolean = False)
    On Error Resume Next
    RangeObject.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:=fileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=OpenAfterPublish
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is that without calling up Adobe, the hyperlinks do not transfer to PDF

Comment: URL hyperlinks work for me.  Bookmark hyperlinks  get flattened. jellz77 uses ExportAsFixedFormat  also an you said that it didn't flatten them.  If you can send me your workbook I'll take a lot.  If not can you post the rest if your code?