# Print Excel sheet into single PDF

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I have an Excel sheet that is populated with data from a database.  As I loop through the data, I write to the same sheet and print it.  I want to put the output into a single PDF.  I'm basically printing the same sheet over and over with different data.  The problem is that instead of adding to the pdf, the pdf gets overwritten each time I export new data.  Below is the code I use to export the sheet.

```
    Sheets("FORM8").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "F:\Reg\Form8\F8.pdf", OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add print area content (appending) at the end of initial existed pdf file in a new page section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46327666/add-print-area-content-appending-at-the-end-of-initial-existed-pdf-file-in-a-n)

Comment: You just want to print all of your sheets as one PDF rather than individual PDF files? (if you do individual you need to throw a time stamp onto the end of the filename to prevent overwrite)

Comment: I just edited the description to be a little clearer.  I want one pdf.

Comment: So put all of the data into the worksheet first, and then do your export.

Comment: See comment below.

Answer (score 0):

You can append the current date and epoch time to the file name to ensure that the file is unique and created into your directory.

```
Dim dateName As String
Dim outputFile As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim epoch As Long

dateName = Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy")
epoch = DateDiff("s", #1/1/1970#, Now())

FileName = dateName + Str(epoch)

outputFile = "F:\Reg\Form8\F8" + FileName + ".pdf"

Sheets("FORM8").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    outputFile, OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Comment: I am creating a single PDF of many reports.  A report is a single Excel sheet.  It is the same sheet used over and over.  I loop through the data, update the sheet and export the sheet to a PDF.  I want to export that sheet into the same PDF file. I want to add to the PDF file, not replace it or create unique PDFs.